# Trying to make A Route

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Trying to make a new route but all in vain, it is not showing anything in Browser
my code for Routes.php

```
<?php


Route::get('/login', array(
    'as' => 'login',
    'uses' => 'AuthController@setIndex'
    )
);
```

and AuthCotroller.php

```
<?php

class AuthController extends Controller{


    public function setIndex(){

        return View::make('layouts.index');

    }

}
```

but in browser when i do that

http://try.com/Laravel/public/login

it shows

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /Laravel/public/login was not found on this server.

Comment: Are you sure you enter correct URL into browser? What is your project base address?

Answer (score 0):

The `as`, `uses` is not necessary you could do the following:

```
<?php

Route::get('/login', 'AuthController@setIndex');
```

And for debugging purposes you could do:

```
<?php

class AuthController extends Controller{

    public function setIndex() {

        return 'Hello, world!';

    }

}
```

Comment: Sir am having the same issue i thought there is something problem in Laravel Installation, or issue is in my Wamp??

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload` or `php artisan dump-autoload` from the root of your project after creating the controller?

Comment: i got the solution, it was just to Enable rewrite_module and restart Wamp.

Comment: yeah a lot and i have been trying for 4 hours

Answer (score 0):

Using WAMP click on wamp icon ->apache->apache modules->scroll and check **rewrite_module** Restart a LoadModule rewrite_module

Note, the server application restarts automatically for you once you enable "rewrite_module"

Got the answer